# How to create temporary view in Spark SQL using a CTE?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm attempting to create a temp view in Spark SQL using a with the statement:

```
create temporary view cars as (
    with models as (
       select 'abc' as model
    )
    select model from models
)
```

But this error is thrown:

```
error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'with' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'DESC', 'VALUES', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DESCRIBE', 'MAP', 'MERGE', 'UPDATE', 'REDUCE'}(line 2, pos 8)

== SQL ==
create temporary view cars as (
        with models as (
--------^^^
           select 'abc' as model
        )
        select model from models
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing brackets after first *as* makes it work:

```
create temporary view cars as 
with models as (
   select 'abc' as model
)
select model from models
```